# Flow for Task Object

Tags: visual-workflow, tasks, scheduled-flow

I have a Use case where I need to send Email to the user about his Today Tasks to his Email ID at 9 Am everyday so that he doesn't need to open SF

So I preferred using Scheduled trigger flow  where I used Get Records with Filters

1. isReminderSet = True

and The second filter I am using is the place where everything is getting out of my hands  I would like to use another filter where the **ReminderDate (Not available) = $Flow.CurrentDate**

The one Which is Available is ReminderDateTime which can be made = $Flow.CurrentDate/Time but the Time needs to be exactly matching to get the Records (One of the Ways I have thought is let the user know that whenever he enters a time it should be 9 Am so that I can schedule the Flow at 9 Am and thereby the filter matches)

Also , Unfortunately there is no field of Date type in the Task which can be used here in the second Filter ![image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for including the context of your question. This allows me to suggest what I believe to be a cleaner solution for your need.

What I think you should do is build a Task report using the Tasks and Events Report Type, filtered to just his tasks and subscribe him to the report, set to run each morning at 9am. Or you could use the "My Tasks" filter and log in as him to set the subscription if you want other users to be able to use this report as well.